# Move Row in SQL DB from one table to another using VB.NET based on Date from date/time picker

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to move rows from a table 1 to table 2 in a SQL DB within a VB.NET app, and I can't figure out how to do get this to work. the latest I have tried is using a CAST. Basically I want to be able to move all rows for a specified person where the rows DateOfService is before a specified date (txtInsReset.Text)

```
With OleDBC

  .Connection = conn
                
  .CommandText = "Insert Into TblArchive SELECT * FROM TblServiceLog WHERE TblServiceLog.PatientID = '" & txtPatientID.Text & "' AND TblServiceLog.DateOfService < cast('" & txtInsReset.Text & "' as DATETIME)"
                
  .ExecuteNonQuery()
            
End With
```

Comment: You're not moving anything. You're retrieving data from one table, inserting it into another, then deleting it from the first. Do you know how to perform those three operations? If not, where's the actual problem?

Comment: You don't need to cast anything. If you're using ADO.NET then you should be using parameters to insert values into SQL code. That is what you should be looking into. [Here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) is my take on the subject.

Comment: Stop concatenating user input into your SQL. Google *Little Bobby Tables** for the reasons why, then search again for *VB.Net parameterized queries* for the proper way to do things. Also, terminology is important - you can't *move a row* using SQL. You can SELECT it from one table to INSERT it into another, and then DELETE it from the original table. A good SQL tutorial will make things much easier for you going forward, and learning the basics will save you a lot of frustration going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commentors have commented, there is no "move" option in MS SQL. The process is to insert into a table, then delete from the original table.

Here is how to do that with a stored procedure. This is my preferred method of doing it if I'm not using EntityFramework.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MoveToArchive
   @id INT
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO TblArchive
    (
        productName
       ,description
    )
    SELECT productName, description FROM TblServiceLog WHERE id = @id

    DELETE FROM TblServicelog WHERE id = @id


END
```

Then you can execute the stored procedure like this

```
Using DBConnection As New SqlConnection("myconnectionstring"),
            MySqlCommand As New SqlCommand("MoveToArchive", DBConnection),
            MySqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(MySqlCommand)
            MySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", foo) 
    
            DBConnection.Open()

            MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    
            DBConnection.Close()
            DBConnection.Dispose()
End Using
```